# How to change the color in the BarChart

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi i have this BarChart that shows the procent of some dadta. How to change the color of the bar if the procent is < 20 in red for example?

This is My Barchart:

```
          <BarChart
            //style={graphStyle}
            style={{marginBottom: -20}}
            data={this.state.chartData}
            width={screenWidth - 40}
            height={220}
            //yAxisLabel="$"
            chartConfig={this.state.chartConfig}
            verticalLabelRotation={30}
          />

          <View style={{padding: 5, paddingTop: 0}}>
            {
              this.state.labels.map((obj, i) => {
                return (
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 14, marginBottom: 2.5, color: '#666'}}>{i+1}. {obj} ({this.state.chartData.datasets[0].data[i]} gallons({this.state.procent[i]}%))</Text>
                )
              })
            }
          </View>
```

This is chartConfig:

```
       const chartConfig = {
     backgroundGradientFrom: "#fff",
     //backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 0,
     backgroundGradientTo: "#fff",
      //backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0.5,
      color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
     strokeWidth: 1, // optional, default 3
     barPercentage: 0.75,
  
     useShadowColorFromDataset: false // optional
   };
```

Where to add a second color if my procent of data is lover than 20?

This is the picture how it looks.

[image]

And if someone knows i am doing a formula to get the procent for the barchart and the Barchart expects data ti fill the vertical row with numbers how can i hardCode it so the number is always 100 at the top of the y?

Answer (score 1):

Since version `6.7.0` you can use the `withCustomBarColorFromData` prop as introduced with [this PR](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/pull/429).

This works as follows:

- Set the `withCustomBarColorFromData` prop to `true`
- Provide a `colors` array within your data object. There is bijection between the indices of the colors array and the data indices. You need to provide a function that maps the opacity to a color string.

In order to have a custom color if the data point is less then 20, you could manage a separate colors state containing all the necessary functions.

Here is minimal example.

```js
const init = [19, 18, 25, 20, 16];

const MyBarChart = () => {
  const [colors, setcolors] = useState(init.map(item => (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`))
  const [data, setData] = useState(init)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setcolors(data.map(item => item < 20 ? (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 0, 0, ${opacity})` : (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`))
  }, [data])

 const dataset = {
    labels: ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: data,
        colors: colors
      }
    ]
  }

  return (
    <>
      <BarChart
        data={dataset}
        width={300}
        height={220}
        withCustomBarColorFromData={true}
        flatColor={true}
        chartConfig={{
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          backgroundGradientFrom: '#ffffff',
          backgroundGradientTo: '#ffffff',
          data: dataset.datasets,
          color: (opacity = 1) => '#fff',
          labelColor: () => '#6a6a6a',
      }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

The result is as follows.

[image]

Comment: Do u know how can i the vertical left numbers to set as a % from 0 to 100 and organize the data via the procent number

Comment: You are responsible for setting the dataset. The component just visualizes this in bar chart. Hence, you need to implement a function that normalizes your dataset the way you prefer. This is not related to your initial question, though. This might be more suitable for a new question.